# How to configure bash to print utf8 error message?

Tags: bash, utf-8, freebsd

Strange UTF-8 handling in bash.

```
$ á
bash: $'\303\241': command not found
```

when run tcsh, so

```
$ tcsh   #or exec tcsh
> á
á: Command not found.
```

What can be wrong? How to setup bash for utf8 correctly?

<sup>And before mark this question as duplicate, please, read the next too:</sup>

My `.inputrc`:

```
set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set output-meta on
set convert-meta off

set show-all-if-ambiguous On

"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward

set -o vi
```

my ENV:

```
LOCALE=UTF-8;           export LOCALE
LESSCHARSET='utf-8';    export LESSCHARSET
LANG=en_US.UTF-8;       export LANG
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8;     export LC_ALL
```

IMO, i have done all what must be done for utf8 handling in bash.

bash version:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.28(0)-release (amd64-portbld-freebsd9.0)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Works for me: `$ á` gives me `á: command not found` (similar environment)

Comment: AFAIK, it should work. Therefore need ideas what can be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's new in Bash 4.2. See [this](http://old.nabble.com/UTF8-conversion-issues-in-bash-4.2-td31367363.html).

> There is a change in bash-4.2 that prints characters in error messages 
>   using ANSI-C escapes if isprint() fails for any character in the string. 
>   It's intended to make things like \r in filenames visible.  It came in 
>   from cygwin, but is generally useful.
>
> Chet

Chet Ramey is the maintainer of Bash.

Comment: Ouch... that's is terrible. I'm wondering why `isprint(*wchar)` failing on correctly utf-8 enabled environment. Anyway, thanx for the info. Good bye, bash - staying with tcsh. ;)