# How to get properly encoded apache error.log with tailf?

Tags: php, apache, encoding, utf-8

I have code which can error with russian language message.

For example:

```
Неверно составлен limit
```

But error.log contains:

```
\xd0\x9d\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe \xd1\x81\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd limit
```

Is there way to read with tailf error.log normally (with `sed` or something)?

Or how I can "tell" to apache do not encode utf symbols error.log?

Comment: Perhaps your viewer is not using the UTF8 encoding? Do you use bash.  Version 4.2 perhaps?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952505/how-to-configure-bash-to-print-utf8-error-message

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After couple tries I found the solution.

`echo -e` -- to get utf insead of hex.

`tailf ... | while read line; do command; done;` -- to read output of tailf by line

`read -r` -- to avoid of convert escape sequence.

So, result is:

```
tailf /var/log/apache2/error.log | while read -r line; do echo -e "$line"; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to use [enca](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enca) in your case, and if you don't know exactly what type of output encoding you have you might also use the options available in it such as `-g, --guess`
you can have it from [gitorious](https://gitorious.org/enca#more).

a simple description, and I'm paraphrasing here:

> If you are lucky enough, the only two things you will ever need to know are: command

```
enca FILE
```

and to know what type of encoding your file uses you can try:

```
enconv FILE
```

obviously you will need to replace **FILE** with your error log. 
after that you can simply try something like:

```
tail -20f /path/to/your/file/error_log
```

to download your file.

Comment: Did you try it with `tailf`?

Comment: @sectus - `tailf` should work also, but no I didn't, and actually there's no reason for it not to work, as the `enca` would already changed the encoding of the file.Thus, fetching with `tailf` wouldn't be a problem!

Comment: `tailf` allows to read log file in "real time". It would be really hard to achieve it with copying.

Comment: @sectus - even though, the execution of `enca` is in microtime, so **realtime** wouldn't be a problem. 
anyway, glad that you figured out a way to solve your problem :)

Comment: Could you write complete command to read file with `tailf`. I think that I cannot understand your solution completely.

Comment: Ah. There's no much to show. Ssh to your file. Use enca to change the encoding accordingly then use tailf as you suggested in your answer without `-e`.

Comment: Tailf allow to follow to changes of file. So i cannot to use enca with this approach.

Comment: @sectus - I see what you mean, and that's why I +1'ed your answer :)
as you are reading the file, tailf helps you read in real time but what enca does, is just change the encoding of the already exists lines which will not be applied on new (real-time) lines. 
That's my mistake here, I should have guessed that you are using tailf with a purpose.
once again glad that you figured it out, and I'll keep the answer so someone else might benefit from it ;)